# Unable use data-fetch function

Tags: reactjs, next.js

### Objective

I want to pass the `itemsData` obtained from `getEquipment()` to the `ItemsDataContextProvider`.

### Issue/Unknown:

Despite attempting various methods, I'm unable to find a way to successfully obtain `itemsData`.

### Error Message:

error Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding `'use client'` to a module that was originally written for the server.

**getEquipmentinfo.ts:**

```js
'use server';
import { JWT } from 'google-auth-library'; // Authentication.
import { GoogleSpreadsheet } from 'google-spreadsheet';
import { itemProps } from 'const/equipmentType';

// Get the sheet instance.
const getSheets = () => {
  // First, create authentication information.

  // Scopes for visibility.
  const scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
  ];
  // Spreadsheet ID from process.env, specified in .env.local
  const sheetId = process.env.SHEET_ID;
  // Service account email and path
  const clientEmail =
    process.env.GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL;
  const privateKey = (
    process.env.GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY as string
  ).replace(/\\n/g, '\n');

  // Create authentication instance
  const jwt = new JWT({
    email: clientEmail,
    key: privateKey,
    scopes: scopes,
  });

  // Set the sheet ID and authentication information to generate the spreadsheet instance
  const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(sheetId as string, jwt);
  return doc;
};

// Function to retrieve data of type itemProps[]
export const getEquipmentInfo = async () : Promise<itemProps[]> => {
  // Create a sheet instance
  const sheet = getSheets();
  // Get data from GCP
  await sheet.loadInfo();
  // Get the sheet named "equipments"
  const sheetInfo = sheet.sheetsByTitle['equipments'];

  // Retrieve column data from the sheet
  const rows = await sheetInfo.getRows<itemProps>();
  console.log(rows);
  if (rows) {
    // Convert to an array of dictionaries and return each data
    return rows.map((row) => {
      return {
        name: row.get('name'),
        count: row.get('count'),
        tag: row.get('tag'),
        location: row.get('location'),
        imagePath: row.get('imagePath'),
        latestUpdate: row.get('latestUpdate'),
        purchasePlace: row.get('purchasePlace'),
        threshold: row.get('threshold'),
      };
    });
  } else {
    // Prevent items from becoming undefined by returning an error here.
    // Reference: https://zenn.dev/estra/articles/ts-with-promise-type-annotation#promise-%E3%81%AE%E5%9E%8B%E6%B3%A8%E9%87%88
    return [];
  }
}
```

**itemsContext.tsx:**

```js
'use client';
import { ReactNode, createContext, use, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { itemProps } from '@/lib/const/equipmentType';
import { getEquipmentInfo } from '@/lib/apis/getEquipmentInfo';

export const ItemsDataContext = createContext({
  itemsData: [] as itemProps[],
});

export const ItemsDataContextProvider = ({
  children,
}: {
  children: ReactNode;
}) => {
    const [itemsData, setItemsData] = useState<itemProps[]>([]);
    useEffect(() => {   
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const data = await getEquipmentInfo();
            setItemsData(data);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);
  return (
    <ItemsDataContext.Provider value={{ itemsData }}>
      {children}
    </ItemsDataContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

### Additional Information/Attempts:

I have tried various methods, including using Server Actions, but I keep receiving the error: "It is not allowed to define inline 'use server' annotated Server Actions in Client Components. To use Server Actions in a Client Component, you can either export them from a separate file with 'use server' at the top, or pass them down through props from a Server Component."

### Supplemental:

Reference Articles
I'm aware that data is being retrieved from the console.log within getEquipment.
Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you.